# Slack API reminders.add not working with bot token: not_allowed_token_type

Tags: aws-lambda, slack-api

I have set up a Slack Bot, which is interacting with an AWS Lambda, which is working fine. From the lambda, a text message is returned and printed accordingly in the appropriate channel or thread. So far so good. Now I want that lambda to add a reminder, thus I gave it the reminder:write and reminder:read (optional) scopes.

However, the lambda (please use the [link](https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add/test) to reproduce the error) and the [Slack API tester](https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add/test) (use for testing) are both returning: `not_allowed_token_type` although I am using `xoxb-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX` token.

In the end the reminder should be equivalent to:

```
/remind #bot-testing "@EC2Handler Stop EC2 Instance" in 30 seconds
```

with EC2Handler being my Slack App-Bot.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: After some further work I figured out two things:

1. `xoxb` is not the correct key type but `xoxp`, which is the user oauth-token.
2. The `reminders.add` method cannot add a reminder for a bot from the lambda directly. See [this thread](https://forums.slackcommunity.com/s/question/0D5Hq00009gDm6UKAS/slack-api-remindersadd-not-working-with-bot-token-notallowedtokentype?language=en_US).

As a workaround, I let the lambda set a general reminder not addressing my self-made bot. Following this approach, the slack-bot (which comes with slack, NOT my self-made bot) will print the reminder into the channel. The message being posted triggers my first lambda function (first one responding with 200 HTTP and forwarding the event to a second lambda). Within the first lambda functions, I filter all posted messages (e.g. User-ID or trigger type) so that only the messages, which are important are actually processed in my second lambda causing a new reminder to be set.
Here is the python function from my lambda creating a reminder:

```
def set_slack_reminder(event, text, time):
    SLACK_ADD_REMINDER_URL = "https://slack.com/api/reminders.add"
    channel = event.get("channel")
    token = "xoxp-XXX"
    
    
    
    reminder_data = {
        "token": token,
        "channel": channel,
        "text": text,
        "time": time,
    }

    # Make the request to add the reminder
    add_reminder_request = urllib.request.Request(SLACK_ADD_REMINDER_URL, data=urllib.parse.urlencode(reminder_data).encode("ascii"), method="POST")
    add_reminder_request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    print('Fire off the reminder request!')
    add_reminder_response = urllib.request.urlopen(add_reminder_request).read()
    print(add_reminder_response)
```